# Github actions docker cache invalidation

Tags: docker, caching, github-actions

in my actions I am using the `gha` export type like:

```
- uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1
- name: Build & Push
  uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
  with:
      cache-from: type=gha,scope=${{ matrix.ecr_repo }}
      cache-to: type=gha,mode=max,scope=${{ matrix.ecr_repo }}
      push: true
      tags: "${{ env.tags }}"
```

However when the action is building I sometimes have lines that should be cached suddenly invalidated.

e.g:

```
#20 [base 22/26] COPY src/go.sum ./
#20 CACHED
#30 [base 23/26] RUN go mod download
#30 sha256:fccecca06c0e928afeb80a372e92178cfe09778a2d41c53d690328cd9350920f 43.01kB / 43.01kB 0.1s done
#30 sha256:46e25f3fb1d9354adea3ee0ec11523a2d4bdb24c795548575f2a8a180f8ef285 2.53kB / 2.53kB 0.1s done
...
```

Dockerfile:

```
...

COPY src/go.mod ./
COPY src/go.sum ./
RUN go mod download


COPY src ./
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/go-build \
    go build -tags=static -o /cli && ls -al /cli

...
```

I don't understand why `RUN go mod download` is not cached when the COPY before is - is there any debugging I can do?

Comment: Did you look into this: https://github.com/docker/buildx/issues/518 ? Is this related?

Comment: If the file from the previous dockerfile instructions e.g. COPY have a different checksum, it can invalid the cache for the following instructions.